# C#: Отсортировать элементы списка по частоте

Tags: c#, списки, сортировка, python, список

Что-то я не соображу никак. На Пайтоне я могу написать вот так:

```
freq = [ (lst.count(i), i) for i in set(lst) ]
freq.sort()
```

В качестве бонуса элементы с одинаковой частотой сортируются по самим элементам, как таковым. Это приятно. На C# 3.0 кортежей нет, да и в более новых версиях я не уверен, что они работают именно так, как в Пайтоне. Пожалуйста, не предлагайте реализовать свой класс для пайтоноподобных кортежей, это явно оверинжиниринг. :) Я тогда уж лучше со сдвигом бит заморочусь. То есть в 32-битном числе старшие 16 бит отдам под счетчик чисел, 16 - под само число (для моей задачи хватит с избытком). Пока что ничего умнее не придумал... :(

```
uint[] freq = new uint[100];
// lst - список чисел от 0 до 100, длина списка не более 65535 чисел.
foreach (int i in lst)
{
    freq[i]++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < freq.Length; i++)
{
    freq[i] <<= 16;
    freq[i] += i;
}
Array.Sort(freq);
```

Как-то уж очень это "по-сишному". Потом придется эти данные вытаскивать тоже с помощью битовых операций... Все же XXI век на дворе, хотелось бы более "функционально", что ли...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    list.GroupBy(p => p)
        .Select(p => new { Value = p, Count = p.Count() })
        .OrderBy(p => p.Count)
        .ToList() // если с просмотром частоты вхождения каждого значения

    list.GroupBy(p => p).OrderBy(p=>p.Count()) // ASC по вашему вопросу
    list.GroupBy(p => p).OrderByDescending(p=>p.Count()) // DESC по вашему вопросу
```